# Physics Issues: Objects set to Active nor behaving has they should be

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm exploring some tutorials about force fields and rigid bodies, and i found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZG_ZMnKzVTQ
All went well, i had just completed the tutorial, but out of now where the pieces of the sphere started behaving differently compared to what i obtained from the tutorial, basically instead of scattering according to the force field, they scatter way sooner and in a different shape than what it should be according the tutorial.

[image]

I already tried to delete the force field and the Typography, but the result were exactly the same. Also the force field is animated, at frame 100 the strength is 0 and then it goes all the way to 100k strength, so the rock should start moving more or less at frame 110.

[image]

Only the pieces of the sphere

Comment: Could be a lot of reasons. e.g. you have another Blender version than in your tutorial. The add-on might be on another version. And maybe you just missed a little detail in the tutorial. Just my opinion: i would not spent too much time on getting the 100% result of the tutorial. Important is just that you learn the technique.

Comment: i totaly understand, but it was going fine, i didnt update anything at all, just made a new scene and started working on other effecs, and when i came back to the first scene it was like that =/ besides i delete the the force field, since the dont have any colision object, and there is no gravity, they should be in the same place at least, right?